# How can I handle "Null" values when returning a Python dictionary through Thrift?

Tags: python, server, thrift

I am using Thrift for a micro-service written in python.
I am returning a dictionary in python which can contain `NULL` values.

This is the code for my Python response handler:

```
def response(id, token):
    user_record = usertable.objects.get(uid = id)
    if user_record.token == token:
        response = dict(
            pa_uid = user_record.pa_uid,
            pa_token = user_record.pa_token,
            dev_id = user.dev_id
        )
        return response
```

The `response` function is the returning a dictionary and the `dev_id` key has a `NULL` value in many cases.
How can I to handle this in Thrift?

This is the code in my Thrift file:

```
service Calculator extends shared.SharedService {
  map<string,string>  response(1:string id, 2:string token),
}
```

When the `dev_id` key has a `NULL` value Thrift does not return a dictionary and an error is thrown by the Thrift Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

**The ternary conditional operator**

You can use the ternary conditional operator in the `dev_id` assignment.

```
dev_id = user.dev_id if user.dev_id != None else 'not_found'
```

Now u can check for 'not_found' value in the dictionary and handle it appropriately.

**The `or` logical operator**

The other option is to use `or` in assignment as Tom Barron has answered

```
dev_id = user.dev_id or 'no_dev'
```

**Note:** The use of `or` doesn't eliminate the corner case where the `user.dev_id` can have a falsy value like `0` in case of number or empty string in case of strings. Such falsy values will trigger `or` and assign `'no_dev'` to `dev_id`. If such falsy values needs to be preserved then use the ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to do use a value that is never a valid `dev_id` value to indicate its absence:

For example:

```
def response(id, token):
    user_record = usertable.objects.get(uid = id)
    if user_record.token == token:
        response = dict(
            pa_uid = user_record.pa_uid,
            pa_token = user_record.pa_token,
            dev_id = user.dev_id or 'no_dev'
        )
        return response
```

Then you can watch for the `no_dev` value in Thrift and do whatever is appropriate when `dev_id` has not been defined.

Shankar makes a good point in his answer: if 0 is a valid user.dev_id value, you'll need to use a ternary operator to set the dev_id member of the dictionary since otherwise you'll incorrectly get 'no_dev'.

Comment: No problem, it was a great answer, all I did was make the code a bit easier to understand ;)

Comment: What if the `user.dev_id` is 0 ? The `or` will still kick in and `dev_id` is assigned `'no_dev'`.